# Regular expression to match a line starting with a digit only if the same line contains letters after

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, subtitle, geany

I have a text/subtitle file like below:

```
1
00:00:58,178 --> 00:00:59,327
Some text!

2
00:00:59,329 --> 00:01:01,819
<i>Some text</i>

3
00:01:40,512 --> 00:01:41,629
2350 some text.

4
00:01:41,631 --> 00:01:43,771
Some text.
```

Now I have almost figured out, how to match the actual subtitle line by the below regular expression:

```
^([^\d^\n].*)
```

But what if the same actual subtitle line starts with digit(third subtitle in example)? So now I have to match also those lines starting with digits only if they later have letters in the same line before line ending.

How can I do that by combining with my above used regular expression?

Comment: What if the subtitle line is just a number? Also, try this approach: [`^(?!\d+$|\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+ --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+$).+`](https://regex101.com/r/dPTc6v/2)

Comment: Can the text also contain colons?  Like `Some:text`?

Comment: Well for this case (susbitle starting with number) I can safely ignore it, as regex will clash with subtitle serial numbers too. Chances of actual subtitle line containing only numbers are relevantly low compared to whole subtitle file, but if this can be avoided then it will definitely be a more best-case/ideal-case scenario.

Comment: If subtitle line contains special characters then also it is fine, but as I mentioned in my question, the critical thing is it shouldn't start with digit for most cases except when lines starting with digits also contain alphabets later-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update #1**

*This update is made to bring a huge performance boost*

I suppose subtitles can be in multi lines:

```
^\d+:\d+:[^-]+-->.*\R+\K.+(?:\R.+)*(?=\s*(?:^\d+$|\z))
```

Explanation:

```
^\d+:\d+:[^-]+-->.*     # Match time's line
\R+\K                   # One or more newlines (& forget all previous matched characters)
.+                      # Match next immediate line
(?:\R.+)*               # And continuing lines of subtitle (if any)
(?=\s*(?:^\d+$|\z))     # Up to a digit-only-line or end of input string
```

**[Live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/jWOqAq/5)**

Comment: Thanks for great answer, but this regex also matches the newline(which serves as partition between subtitles) after the content is over, can this be avoided somehow ?

Comment: That makes this answer the perfect one by far many thanks, I think this will work with any ugly subtitle files, I ever work with in the future too. Even then if you find any improvements feasible, then you're welcome to improve it further. Btw, if you find this question worthy, you're welcome to upvote it.

Comment: Matching the previous line is a good idea, because it consumes lines that need to be exclude. Since this kind of file has always the same structure and each block ends with an empty line, you can even have the luxury to be more evasive: `^\d+:.*\R\K.+(?:\R.+)*`

Comment: I just updated answer according to your comment. It's totally helpful. Thank you. @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: Thanks for the update, as regex is a vast area and there are many-many combinations of characters, which gives us more choices to make regexes better performance oriented, your info is really worth implementing and thanks to all for their useful comments.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an approach that consists in ignoring all lines that are only numbers or are equal to the SRT timestamp period:

```
^(?!\d+$|\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+ --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+$).+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dPTc6v/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?!` - start of the negative lookahead that will fail the match if a pattern is found immediately to the right:

  - `\d+$` - 1+ digits up to the end of line
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+ --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+$` - the `-->` separated timestamps
- `)` - end of the lookahead
- `.+` - match the whole non-empty line

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks a lot. Please don't delete it, you are welcome to edit/improve it.

Comment: I see you prefer a more precise regex. Note that revo's regex is using lazy dot matching pattern (you do not need `[\s\S]` if you replace it with a `.` and use a DOTALL modifier) that, together with a lookahead at the end is a resource consuming pattern. Use [`^\d+:\d+:[^-]+-->.*\R\K.+(?:\R(?!\d+$).*)*`](https://www.regex101.com/r/jWOqAq/4). Note that the step amount gets reduced 4 times with this version. Actually, I'd still prefer a more verbose part matching the timestamp (`\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+ --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+$`).

Comment: Note too, the `[^-]` matches a line break, so you might want to replace it with `[^-\r\n]`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I see that `[\s\S]` has been removed by revo and now his regex is less lines consuming than before. Also nice catch for matching `[^-\r\n]` as that would be the case with Windows editors, but I think removing `\r+` first is also taking me to the same solution, to mention with couple steps than one, so I would definitely try your updated information too.

Comment: Actually, revo is now using Casimir's suggestion and basically matching non-empty lines starting from the timestamp. I do not want to code-golf with them unless you do not want to call it a day. I think my suggestion is good enough as it is given your requirements.